# Renaming long MongoDB column names to shorter ones, in a live app

Tags: mongodb, key, rename

Like most folks coming from a Relational background, we stuck with rather large column names. Now the code + App is coded & tested. But Mongo best practices note that [key names should be short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790861/is-shortening-properties-names-worth-it) as every column name is stored with-in each document. To complicate things further, we are using the Mongo drivers directly, without any mapping layer like Morphia etc.

**Let me rephrase:** Even if I use $rename to rename the columns, the client APP is still using the longer names. Then I need to do some kind of JSON Transformation, on each document going out & coming in: on the way out {U: "", C:""} will need to become {Updated:"", Created: ""}. Vice-versa on the way-in.

Comment: Are you asking about updating the field names in your mongo collections are are you asking how to update your code? Can you edit your question to be more clear on this.

Comment: It's not a best practice that is just some guys opinion. You should really evaluate the situation and understand if you actually need this. I should mention that the reason you state is not the reason why field names take so much space. The reason is that there isnot compression of field names yet, that will soon hopefully change though

Answer (score 1):

You can rename keys one by one in all records with a multi update using the [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator, which updates the name of a field:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename:{"foo":"bar"}}, false, true);
```

The options are `false` for upsert, and `true` for multi-update.

Comment: I was also able to rename the nested key using "foo.bar1":"foo.bar2"

Comment: Is there a way to rename the key which is an array? Say foo.bar is an array containing [{"name":"n1"},{"name":"n2"}]. How do we change "name" to "firstName"?